# One pod per DAG instead of one pod per task with Airflow Kubernetes Executor?

Tags: kubernetes, airflow

We decided to run Airflow on Kubernetes. We would like to make use of the power of Kubernetes, but in a balanced way.
We have some very small tasks in our DAGs, for example create a directory. The KubernetesExecutor spins up a pod for every task, this takes long and therefore is overkill for many short tasks.

My question is, is it possible to configure Airflow to spin up a Kubernetes pod for a whole DAG, instead of a pod per task? (Preferably without Celery)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is possible to use one pod per DAG, because [KubernetesExecutor is designed to request a pod per task](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/executor/kubernetes.html#kubernetesexecutor-architecture):

> When a DAG submits a task, the KubernetesExecutor requests a worker pod from the Kubernetes API. The worker pod then runs the task, reports the result, and terminates.

Maybe combining multiple smaller tasks into one is a way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Too bad that this is not possible, would have been nice to have some sort of configuration how you would want to use Kubernetes. The thing is, I think combining multiple small tasks goes against Airflow design principles.

Comment: @Databash If this answered your question consider upvoting and accepting. Regarding "Airflow design principles", I don't think there is anything prescribing how fine granular your tasks should be.

Answer (score 0):

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/executor/celery_kubernetes.html

The CeleryKubernetes Executor allows you to use the immediate resources of a celery worker or spin up a pod for a task. I haven’t configured this setup but it seems to match your use case.